# How can I re-write this code to make it run with better performance

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have 2 dataframes:

DataFrame `T` and Dataframe `data`

Both have a column `text` where there's a phrase that I want to compare. The  `calc` line in the code below if the function to make the similarity calculation. It's working.

**What the code do:**

The code look for the first line in `T` and make this calculation for every line of `data` and append the results to a new dataframe `df`.  Then the process goes to the second line of `T` and so on..

Everything is working. There's no error BUT this process takes a lot of time to complete.

**What I need:**
I was wondering if there's a *better way* to code the loops below to make the code runs faster.

```
# Create an empty dataframe
  df = pd.DataFrame()
  d = t.copy()
  for x, y in d.iterrows():
    for k, v in data.iterrows():
     calc = nlp(y['text']).similarity(nlp(v['text']))

     df=df.append(...
```